# how to import the model in sequelize index.ts file

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

how to import the model in sequelize index.ts file as I am new to typescript??

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import { DataTypes, Sequelize} from "sequelize";
import sequalizeConfig from "../config/sequelize";
import  {DB}  from "../types/db";

import { AbnormalityDescriptions } from "../models/abnormalityDescriptions";



const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
const config = sequalizeConfig[env];

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.username,
  config.password,
  config
);
const db = {
  sequelize,
  Sequelize,
  anormalityDescriptions:AbnormalityDescriptions(Sequelize,sequelize.DataTypes)

};
Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
export default db as DB;
```

y model looks like this:

```
export class AbnormalityDescriptions extends Model {
  public abId: number;
  public description: string;

  
 
  
  public static associate = (models: DB) => {
    // associations can be defined here
    models.AbnormalityDescriptions.belongsTo(models.AbnormalityReports, {
      foreignKey: "abnormalityReportId"
    });
  };
}

export default (sequelize: Sequelize, dataTypes: typeof DataTypes) => {
  console.log("here")
  AbnormalityDescriptions.init(
    {
      abId: dataTypes.INTEGER,
      description: dataTypes.STRING,
     
   
     
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: "abnormalityDescriptions"
    }
  );
  return AbnormalityDescriptions;
};
```

```
    Value of type 'typeof AbnormalityDescriptions' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new

node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:434
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
```

The error I got can anyone suggest how to import this model in sequelize index file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're importing named export `AbnormalityDescriptions` here:

```ts
import { AbnormalityDescriptions } from "../models/abnormalityDescriptions";
```

But in fact you need to import `default` export from that file:

```ts
import AbnormalityDescriptions from "../models/abnormalityDescriptions";
```